# How to get the column name in pandas based on row values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df:

```
        id_0         id_1          id_2
0         1            0             1
1         1            0             0
2         0            1             0
3         1            1             0
4         0            0             1
5         0            0             0
```

I want to get the column name for each row if there is 1. How to do that? Thank you.

Result:

```
           result
0         id_0, id_2
1         id_0
2         id_1
3         id_0, id_1
4         id_2
5         NaN
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `dot`

```
df.dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1]
Out[168]: 
0    id_0,id_2
1         id_0
2         id_1
3    id_0,id_1
4         id_2
5             
dtype: object
```

Comment: `df.dot(df.columns+",").str[:-1].replace('',np.nan)` replacing empty with NaN

Answer (score 3):

Let's try `np.argwhere` + `groupby`.

```
v = np.argwhere(df.values).T
(pd.DataFrame(
       df.columns[v[1]], index=df.index[v[0]], columns=['result']
   ).groupby(level=0).agg(','.join).reindex(df.index)
)

      result
0  id_0,id_2
1       id_0
2       id_1
3  id_0,id_1
4       id_2
5        NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

One way may be to try using `lambda` with `zip` and `.join`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(c for c, i in zip(x.index, x.values) if i != 0), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
0    id_0,id_2
1         id_0
2         id_1
3    id_0,id_1
4         id_2
5             
dtype: object
```

Comment: Could you please how this works? I don't get how x.index and x.values could help in this case

Answer (score 2):

With `apply` and `filter`

```
df.mul(df.columns).apply(lambda x: ','.join(filter(bool, x)), 1)

0    id_0,id_2
1         id_0
2         id_1
3    id_0,id_1
4         id_2
5             
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['New'] = [','.join([str(df.columns[x]) for x,y in enumerate(list(i[-1])) if y==1]) for i in df.iterrows()]
print(df['New'])
```

Output:

```
0    id_0,id_2
1         id_0
2         id_1
3    id_0,id_1
4         id_2
5             
Name: New, dtype: object
```